# Shifting big numbers

Tags: c++, linked-list, bit-manipulation, biginteger, shift

`X = 712360810625491574981234007851998` is represented using a linked list and each node is an `unsigned int`

[image: linked list of 712360-810625491-574981234-007851998]

Is there a fast way to do <strike>`X << 8`</strike> `X << 591` other than <strike>`X * 2^8`</strike> `X * 2^591` ?

Comment: If you split your numbers into a list of single bytes, a shift left by eight would be equivalent to adding one more element to the end of your linked list.

Comment: Right, or along the same lines, if each element in the list is a 4 or 8 byte int, just shift the each element << 8 and use the element's previous high byte as the new low byte of the next list item.

Comment: I don't know if it'll work if you shift with a large number?! I think `X << 8` was a bad example

Comment: It doesn't seem to change things so much to shift by a large amount. If your list element is a 4-byte int, then adding 0x00000000 to the head of your list is a shift by 32. So do that until you are down to a shift less than 32, and then you need to treat the remaining shift amount byte-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Bit shifting is very easy in any arbitrary number of bits. Just remember to **shift the overflowed bits to the next element**. That's all

Below is a left-shift-by-3 example

```
uint64_t i1, i2, i3, o1, o2, o3; // {o3, o2, o1} = {i3, i2, i1} << 3;

o3 = i3 << 3 | i2 >> (32 - 3);
o2 = i2 << 3 | i1 >> (32 - 3);
o1 = i1 << 3;
```

Similar for shifting right, just iterate in the reverse direction.

## Edit:

It seems that **you're using base 10<sup>9</sup>** for your large number, so binary shifting does **not** apply here. "Shifting" left/right N digits in a base B is equivalent to *multiplying the number by B<sup>N</sup> and B<sup>-N</sup>* respectively. You can't do binary shift in decimal and vice versa

If you don't change your base then you have only one solution, that's multiplying the number by 2<sup>591</sup>. If you want to shift like in binary you must change to a [base that is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23840565/995714) like base 2<sup>32</sup> or base 2<sup>64</sup>

A general solution to shift would be like this, with the *limbs* ("digits" or each small word unit in a big integer, in arbitrary-precision arithmetic term) stored in **little-endian** and each digit is in base 2<sup>CHAR_BIT*sizeof(T)</sup>

```
template<typename T,
    class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
void rshift(std::vector<T>& x, std::size_t shf_amount) // x >>= shf_amount
{
    // The number of bits in each limb/digit
    constexpr std::size_t width = CHAR_BIT*sizeof(T);
    if (shf_amount > width)
        throw; // or zero out the whole vector for saturating shift

    // Number of limbs to shift
    const std::size_t limbshift = shf_amount / width;
    // Number of bits to shift in each limb
    const std::size_t shift     = shf_amount % width;
    
    std::size_t i = 0;
    // Shift the least significant bits
    for (; i < x.size() - limbshift - 1; ++i)
        x[i] = (x[i +     limbshift] >> shift) |
               (x[i + 1 + limbshift] << (width - shift));
    x[i] = x[i + limbshift] >> shift;
    i++;
    // Zero out the most significant bits
    for (; i < x.size() ; ++i)
        x[i] = 0;
}
```

Moreover from the tag you're likely using a linked-list for storing the limbs which is not cache-friendly due to elements scattering all around the memory space, and it also wastes a lot of memory due to the *next* pointers. Actually the memory used by pointers and memory allocation is even larger than the memory for storing the data bits in this case. In fact you shouldn't use linked list in most real life problems

- [Bjarne Stroustrup says we must avoid linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34170566/995714)
- [Why you should never, ever, EVER use linked-list in your code again](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/)
- [Number crunching: Why you should never, ever, EVER use linked-list in your code again](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/340797/number-crunching-why-you-should-never-ever-ever-us)
- [Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/25xpre/bjarne_stroustrup_why_you_should_avoid_linked/)
- [Are lists evil?—Bjarne Stroustrup](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists)

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you use 64-bit integer the code should be

```
o3 = i3 << 3 | i2 >> (32 - 3);
...
```