# How are extremely large floating-point numbers represented in memory?

Tags: c, gmp, bigint, largenumber

How do arbitrary-precision libraries like GMP store extremely large floating-point numbers represented in memory?

I would imagine that if for instance you wanted to compute Pi or Euler's constant to say, 2,000,000 digits that you would allocate a massive array of bytes for the digits to the right of the decimal place. Each byte would store 2 decimal place values and the array would be a member of a data structure with the number of digits and number of bytes used to store the value.

Is this how it works?

Comment: You're pretty close. Efficient implementations use a larger base. GMP uses base `2^32` or `2^64` in an array of 32-bit or 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current computers have 32 or 64-bit registers, so doing calculations on bytes is very inefficient. Also, computers work in binary, so using a base that is a power of 2 is more efficient. They'll use base 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> like Mysticial said. Each computer word will store a digit of the number and they work digit-by-digit.

In some cases you don't need much calculations but most of the time you're inputting and outputting decimal characters instead. This case using a base that is a power or 10 is more efficient. You can use base 10<sup>9</sup> in 32-bit computers and 10<sup>19</sup> in 64-bit ones because that's the largest power of 10 you can store in a 32 or 64-bit value

Comment: +1 Yep. `10^9` is what I use in this [dumbed down Pi calculator](https://github.com/Mysticial/Mini-Pi).