# Constant time n left bit-shift of n bits

Tags: bit-manipulation

For bitshifting large integers. I have seen this answer in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032968/449132):

```cpp
uint64_t i1, i2, i3, o1, o2, o3; // {o3, o2, o1} = {i3, i2, i1} << 3;

o3 = i3 << 3 | i2 >> (32 - 3);
o2 = i2 << 3 | i1 >> (32 - 3);
o1 = i1 << 3;
```

But, this only works for maximum 32 left bit-shifts. How can I create a solution with n-bits left shifts? Needs to be constant time.

Comment: Most obvious would be `switch(shift / 32)` and the solution you presented with variants for larger shifts. There is probably a trickier solution with arrays, but I doubt it would be optimal.

Comment: yeah was thinking about something like this.

Comment: are {i3, i2, i1} 32-bit or 64-bit values? in the linked question, the question is about "unsigned int" values representing the limbs of the larger integer.  If the i values are holding 64-bits, then you'll want (64 - shift) instead.

Comment: @VincentLucarelli yeah true.

Comment: Now, I know why it was 64 bit values. clang and gcc treats bit shifting differently when overflowed. On gcc it becomes zero if the bitshift is larger than the size of the operand. In clang, it wraps around again. To handle the clang case you need to use 64 bit sizes.